# Push new view on front view when using PKRevealController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am using `PKRevealController` to display a left side controller.

The `PKReveal` is connected to my main view controller which is a navigation controller.

I would like when pressing an option from the left side menu it will push a view controller (which is connected to the main view using segue - I use Storyboard).

I'm trying to make it happen from the left side VC - I use the `PushViewController` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you've already overcome this issue, anyway:

Test the class of your RevealController.frontViewController. If it's a navigationController just call [revealController.frontViewController pushViewController: animated:]

Your reveal controller should be accessible from the leftViewController.
If you use storyboard, just instantiate the viewController you want to push by calling [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: ] then push it from the revealController.frontViewController.

This should work. Don't know if this is what you're looking for. Hope this help.